# CLLocationManager weird behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I have a weird problem.

I have 2 classes:

1. BusinessVC
2. FavoritesVC

In both of them i show the user the current distance from him to some specific point.
In both of the classes i use the EXACT same code for that.

FavoritesVC is presented as modal view controller.

For some reason  **didUpdateLocations / didUpdateToLocation**  methods are getting called ONLY in BusinessVC and NOT in FavoritesVC.

I'm implementing  **CLLocationManagerDelegate**  delegate in both classes.

The code I'm using:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad]; 
     [self locatedMe];
}

-(void) locatedMe{
    NSLog(@"locateMe");
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone]; // whenever we move
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters]; // 100 m
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


// For iOS6
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray  *)locations {

    CLLocation * newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSNumber *lat = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *lon = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    self.userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[lat doubleValue] longitude:[lon doubleValue]];

}


// For earlier then iOS6
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    NSNumber *lat = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *lon = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    self.userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[lat doubleValue] longitude:[lon doubleValue]];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.userLocation);
}
```

Comment: Call `[self locatedMe];` in `viewWillAppear` instead in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

OK! Fixed that by running the code on main thread using this code:

```
-(void) locateMe {
    NSLog(@"locateMe");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
         [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
         [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest]; // 100 m
         [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
         [_locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
     });
```

}